# Need a .Net bag for my enums in my monodroid UI element (Button,TextView...)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to set the Tag of my button inside my custom ListItem in my ListView but a Java.Lang.Object is needed ? In a .Net object world, this Tag property seems inappropriate.

So, I need a way to get/set a .Net bag to my UI element:

```
button.Bag=MYEnumsEnum1;
```

then

```
MyEnums myEnum=(MyEnums)button.Bag;
```

Is it possible with monodroid ?
How can I bypass the problem ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Monodroid, but shouldn't it be `button.Tag`?

Comment: No because it uses Java.Lang.Object instead of System.Object:so casting is unavailable.

Comment: I'm confused.  `button.Tag` needs a Java.Lang.Object?  You use both `Tag` and `Bag` in your question, so it's not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a java object connected to a .net one simply by inheriting from Java.Lang.Object

So you can for example use

```
 class Thing : Java.Lang.Object 
 {
       public MyEnum Value { get; set; }
 }
```

This could be used to store something like:

```
button.Tag = new Thing() { Value = MyEnum.Running };
```

and then extracted again later as:

```
var myEnumValue = ((Thing)button.Tag).Value;
```

---

Here's one wrapper I use:

- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxJavaContainer.cs

This is used in:

- the list adapter for wrapping list item objects: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxBindableListAdapter.cs
- tag storage of bound properties in the last method of https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Binders/MvxBindingLayoutInflatorFactory.cs